# Laravel 5.4 eloquent using with and where

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to get Data if join table not null so i do a query like this

```
 $projects = Project::
            with(array('owner'=> function($query) use ($request){
                $query->where('owner_id',$request->input('owner_id'));
            }))->with('plans')->get();
```

i get all projects with owners if not null and plans but, i want to get projects if owners not null

[image]

so if owner null i want not get project i want to get null [] .

How to resolve this issue and thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`has()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) instead of `with()`:

```
Project::has('owner')->with('plans')->get();
```

This query will load all projects that have an owner and also plans.

If you want to load only projects of a specified owner, use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) instead.

```
Project::whereHas('owner', function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where('owner_id', $request->owner_id);
    })
    ->with('plans')
    ->get();
```